# Add div to default blockquotes in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a div to a default wordpress blockquote?

I want to get something like this whenever I use a blockquote in the wordpress editor.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xipFk

So I want to add a .circle div with a quote to the existing blockquote element whenever a blockquote is used. What is the best way of doing this or what might be a better alternative to get this done?

Comment: Look into what’s called “CSS generated content” – keywords `:before/:after` and `content` property.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), although in most themes jQuery is added by default. But if it is not then just download and link it in your theme's head section or use the default CDN which is as follows:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

After adding jQuery - this is all you need

```
$('blockquote').append('<div class="circle"></div>');
```

This will automatically append the required `div` to every blockquote on your posts. Full code here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2GAT/)